# Link metadata to graphic in Geospatial PDF with iText

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation, geospatial

I am trying to create a Geospatial PDF with iText that contains meta properties of the drawn elements. I have already inserted a georeferenced layer. My objects created with the Graphics2D object are displayed in the "Model Tree" in a tree structure. Their meta information is also displayed correctly.
However, I cannot link the objects in the tree structure to the graphic and I cannot find any documentation on how to do this.

I would like to achieve that when an object is selected with the "Object data tool", its metadata is displayed and vice versa. Furthermore, the option "zoom to selection" should work.

Which properties do I have to set in the PDF or which documentation contains this information?

edit:
In the following screenshot of the Acrobat Reader, I selected the tunnel symbol in the map so that its meta information is also highlighted in the "Model Tree". I would like to create this link between the map and the tree structure.

[image]

I assume "Stm" and "StmOwn" are the properties that need to be inserted but where do their contents come from?

[image]

Comment: @KJ does my edit clarify things a bit?

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. It turns out that my solution was correct all along. The only problem was that I was performing the drawing operations on a PdfTemplate. The template creates an XObject, apparently breaking the "link". If I draw directly on the PdfContentByte, it works.